# Swift - Initializing class variables which are classes

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift. I am having trouble with declaring classes. I have the following -

```
class position_ 
{
    var x: Float = 0
    var y: Float = 0
}

class node_
{
    var label: String = nil
    var coordinates: position_
}
```

Now I can create an `initializer init()` in the `position_` class, like this -

```
class position_ 
{
    var x: Float
    var y: Float
    init()
    {
        x = 0
        y = 0
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can use this initializer in the `node_ class`? Because, without an `init()` function there is no way to initialize the coordinates variable in the `node_ class`. Or is there?
I find it hard to believe that Swift would require me to initialize each of the `position_` variables again in the `node_ class`. In other words is there a better option than the below one?

```
class node_
{
    var label: String
    var coordinates: position_
    init()
    {
        name = nil
        coordinates.x = 0
        coordinates.y = 0
    }
}
```

Also if I want to create another variable say "b" of type `UIButton` how do I initialize that? That is really what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First every `class` name Start with `capitalize` character. So change your node_ class like this

```
class Node
{
    var label: String
    var coordinates: position_
    init()
    {
        name = ""
        coordinates = position_()
    }
}
```

Also change your class `position_` with `Position`. 
 Instead of using `_` try to write class name in `capitalize` first character of each word like this `PositionMarker`. 
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have to initialize every variable again because each time you create new instance of a class, structure or enumeration, their stored properties have initial value.
2. Always try to provide a default value rather then setting a value within an initializer. If a class or structure provides default values for all its properties Swift automatically gives you a default initializer.

   ```
   class Position {  
       var x: Float = 0   
       var y: Float = 20  
   }

   let position = Position() // nice!
   ```
3. Position class is a very simple data construct - it feels like the Struct type would fit better here.
4. Final code - with UIButton

   ```
   struct Position {  
       var x: Float = 0  
       var y: Float = 20  
   }

   class Node {  
       var label = "" // label is inferred to be of type String  
       var coordinates = Position()  
       var button = UIButton(type: .InfoDark)  
   }

   let myNode = Node()
   ```